# jQuery webcam plugin - how to ouptut bigger images?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to figure out if the jQuery Webcam Plugin is capable of outputting images that are bigger than 320x240.

I been using the example code from the documentation (http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) with no luck.

JPEGCam (http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/) is capable of outputting bigger images but unfortinately it can't use ajax to upload the image to the server like the jQuery plugin can.

Comment: this might be hard coded in the library somewhere, search and replace in a text editor might be a way to start

Comment: Hey! I created an issue based on this thread. https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam/issues/12

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: The 320x240 size is hardcoded in **jscam.as** (the main file for the swf binary).
You simply need to change those dimensions and recompile the swf.

```
    // jscam.as
    166. for (var i = 0; i < 240; ++i) {
    becomes: for (var i = 0; i < Stage.height; ++i) {

    169. for (var j=0; j < 320; ++j) {
    becomes: for (var j=0; j < Stage.width; ++j) {

    166. for (var i = 0; i < 240; ++i) {
    becomes: for (var i = 0; i < Stage.height; ++i) {

    169. for (var j=0; j < 320; ++j) {
    becomes: for (var j=0; j < Stage.width; ++j) {
```

Comment: Hi @Paulo! Could you send this change as pull request? https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam/issues/12