# How to get bigger ouptut images with the "jQuery webcam plugin" by Robert Eisele?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, plugins, webcam

I am trying to change the output size of the images captured by the webcam with this [jQuery webcam plugin](https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam). But I cannot get it to work

I have tried to recompile the file `jscam.swf`. I have followed [this instructions](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) and I have read this [issue](https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam/issues/5).

So I have change the `jscam.xml` file like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movie width="640" height="480" framerate="24">
    <background color="#ffffff" />
    <DefineVideoStream width="640" height="480" objectID="1" frames="0" deblocking="0" smoothing="0" codec="0" />
    <frame>
        <library>
            <clip id="clip" objectID="1" />
        </library>
    </frame>
</movie>
```

And the `jscam.as`. I have also read [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403718/jquery-webcam-plugin-how-to-ouptut-bigger-images) and they do the same:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 480; ++i) {

[...]

for (var j=0; j < 640; ++j) {

[...]

for (var i = 0; i < 480; ++i) {

[...]

for (var j=0; j < 640; ++j) {
```

After this I have recompiled the `jscam.swf` , installing the dependencies before

```
sudo apt-get install swfmill mtasc
make
```

This should be enough, but I got the same image size

I have also changed the `js` files of the jQuery plugin, but with the same result.

Comment: So in [**JScam**.as](https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam/blob/master/src/jscam.as) you changed the numbers in both `function save` and `function _stream`?

Comment: Yes, you are right